# What is the area for people to sit in a stadium called?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

[image]

**What is the area for people to sit in a stadium called?**

It seems to be called "**stand**", but I am not sure.

But why "**stand**"?? because people can sit there too?

Can we say "**I was sitting in the stand in the stadium watching Liverpool playing against Manchester City**"?

Comment: Yes, [you can](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-stands), as the first result when searching on "sitting in the stands" shows.

Comment: It's short for [grandstand](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grandstand).

Comment: Stands usually means permanent seating that's at least partially covered. Similar seating that's smaller, more portable and uncovered is called "bleachers." The line between bleachers and stands is not always clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you go back, "Stand" mean something like "hold a position", and was in contrast to "move" or "attack".  The notion of a raised platform, initially as part of a defensive line, then for a hunter, and finally a raised platform for watching sports developed in early modern English.

So, these are indeed called stands, and these stands are fitted with seats, so you sit in the stands.

Many famous stands have names. Liverpool's Anfield stadium has four stands, The Kop, Centenary Stand, Anfield Road End and Main Stand.

Comment: …and of course, you used to actually stand, until 1989. They're also called terraces, because of the stepped structure, perhaps from the farming usage. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terrace

Answer (score 0):

## stands (pl.)

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stands):

> **4 b stands *plural*
>
> (1) :** a section of the tiered seats for spectators of a sport or spectacle